# matrix representation for $φ: \mathbb{R}[t]→ \mathbb{R}^2 f(t) → \begin{pmatrix} f(1) − f(0)\\ f(2) − f(1) \end{pmatrix})$ to the basis$(1,t,t^2,t^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, problem-solving, change-of-basis

I am having problems with this exercise. Can someone help me?

a) Determine the matrix representation for $φ: \mathbb{R}[t]degree≤3 → \mathbb{R}^2 f(t) → \begin{pmatrix} f(1) − f(0)\\ f(2) − f(1) \end{pmatrix})$ with respect to the basis $(1, t, t^2, t^3)$ and the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

b) Determine all polynomials such that $f(2) = f(1) + 1 = f(0) + 2$.

So for a) I found the mapping of the polynomials

So I have $1 \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

$t \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$

$t^2 \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 3\end{pmatrix}$

$t^3 \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 7\end{pmatrix}$

So I have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
 0& 1 &  1&1 \\ 
 0&  1& 3 & 7
\end{pmatrix}$ .

So far everything right?

For the second I am having problems.

What I wanted to do is to try solving this equations system

$\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 &  1&1 \\ 0&  1& 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} f(1)-f(0)\\ f(2)-f(1) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$

But this leads me to the solution $X=\left(\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ 1+2*x_4 \\ -3*x_4 \\ x_4 \end{matrix}\right)$

For which if we think $x_1=1 x_2=t...$ we obtain
$f(t)=t+(1+2)t-3t^2+t^3$

But if I do some tests with this polynomial, they show to me that the answer is wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It's not clear how your equation
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 &  1&1 \\ 0&  1& 3 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} f(1)-f(0)\\ f(2)-f(1) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
is connected to the question being asked

Comment: For that matter, the product of matrices that you've written is not even defined: on the left-hand side, you have the product of a $2 \times 4$ matrix with a $2 \times 1$ matrix, but for a product $AB$  to be defined, the number of columns in $A$ must match the number of rows in $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution for part a is correct.

For part b, we are given the equations
$$
f(2) = f(1) + 1, \quad f(1) + 1 = f(0) + 2.
$$
From there, note that
$$
f(1) + 1 = f(0) + 2 \iff f(1) - f(0) = 1\\
\phantom{1 + ,.}f(2) = f(1) + 1 \iff f(2) - f(1) = 1
$$
Thus, it is equivalent to find the polynomials $f$ satisfying $\pmatrix{f(1) - f(0)\\
f(2) - f(1)} = \pmatrix{1\\1}$ . That is, we wish to solve
$$
\varphi(f) = \pmatrix{1\\1}.
$$
Perhaps now you can see how your matrix from part a can be used.

---

Taking a closer look at your solution, it seems that you have correctly solved the equation
$$
\pmatrix{0&1&1&1\\0&1&3&7}\mathbf x = \pmatrix{1\\1},
$$
which is indeed what you are meant to do. Indeed, the solution is
$$
\mathbf x = \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4} = \pmatrix{x_1\\1 + 2x_4\\-3x_4\\x_4}, \quad x_1,x_4 \in \Bbb R.
$$
From there, you interpreted this solution incorrectly. Letting $\mathcal B$ denote your polynomial basis and $\mathcal S_2$ the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$, the above matrix equation can be written as
$$
[\varphi]_{\mathcal S_2 \leftarrow \mathcal B}[f]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{1\\1},
$$
where we note that $[\varphi]_{\mathcal S_2 \leftarrow \mathcal B}[f]_{\mathcal B} = [T(f)]_{\mathcal S_2}$. Thus, the solutions $\mathbf x$ to the matrix equation can be interpreted as **coordinate-vectors** of the polynomials $f$ satisfying the required condition. So, a vector $f$ will satisfy the desired condition if and only if
$$
[f]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{x_1\\1 + 2x_4\\-3x_4\\x_4}, \quad x_1,x_4 \in \Bbb R \iff\\
f(t) = (x_1)t + (1 + 2x_4)t + (-3x_4)t^2 + (x_4)t^3, \quad x_1,x_4 \in \Bbb R.
$$